# What is the relation between N=2 super Yang-Mills and its twist

Tags: quantum-field-theory, supersymmetry, topological-field-theory

My question is  what is the relation between N=2 super Yang-Mills and its twisted version topological field theory? After twisting N=2 super Yang-Mills, i.e. diagonally embedding $SU(2)'_R$ into $SU(2)_R \times SU(2)_I$, we get a topological field theory. My question is since N=2 SYM and TQFT are  different i.e. one is physical and the other is topological. Why can we use TQFT to calculate partition of N=2 SYM? What are the same for these two different theories?

**Update**: From the second paper of Trimok, the authors claim that SYM under twist are just redefination. How to understand it?

Comment: Not a expert, but they are certainly not the same. Following the original [paper](http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS?service=UI&version=1.0&verb=Display&handle=euclid.cmp/1104161738) ($2.14 \to 2.18$ ) or this [one](http://cds.cern.ch/record/432831/files/0003272.pdf) ($2.3$,$2.4$,$2.30$), the first thing to do  is to decompose  supersymmetric charges and fields under the representations of the new twisted symmetry group $SU(2)_L \times SU(2)'_R  \times U(1)_R$, and to write some action. The $N=2$ twisted action is then shown to be equivalent to a topological Yang-Mills action (+ extra-terms)

Comment: The main difference is that the observables in the topological field theory are only a subset of the observables in the physical theory. The subset consists of $Q$-closed operators, where $Q$ is the scalar supersymmetry charge present in the twisted theory.